# Python loop showing animation with openCV does only work with keypress breaks

Tags: python, opencv

This python script with openCV works when you wait for a key press with `cv2.waitKey(0)`, but it doesn't when I want to make a smooth animation with `time.sleep(0.1)` instead of `cv2.waitKey(0)`. It then shows a cursor symbol that the system gets stuck. Why is this?

```
import cv2
import random
import numpy as np

originalImg = cv2.imread('assets/fluf.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = np.copy(originalImg)

index = 0
while True:
    index += 1
    smallPartImg = originalImg[500:700,index:index+200]
    img[0:200,0:200] = smallPartImg
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Use waitKey(1). OpenCV needs the waitKey command to perform the window rendering

Comment: Ah, it's because it waits 1 msec for the user to press the key. If you have (0) then it there is no time to have the animation (0 msecs)

Comment: waitKey(0) waits forever until a key is pressed. waitKey(1) waits 1 ms or until a key is pressed. Both perform the screen rendering of all previous imshow calls. time.sleep doesn't perform the opencv window rendering.

Comment: Thanks, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the waitKey() number to something not equal to 0. Whatever the number is higher the transition speed makes lower.

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the comments into an Answer (thanks **@Micka**!) to complete this for anyone coming later

> Use waitKey(1). OpenCV needs the waitKey command to perform the window rendering

The issue is that

> waitKey(0) waits forever until a key is pressed. waitKey(1) waits 1 ms or until a key is pressed. Both perform the screen rendering of all previous imshow calls. time.sleep doesn't perform the opencv window rendering.